# svc wifi disable not working programmetically on Android 10/11

Tags: java, android

Following code works well on Android 9. This turns off WIFI on the device.

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process ipProcess = runtime.exec("svc wifi disable");
            int exitValue = ipProcess.waitFor();
            return (exitValue == 0);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
```

The same code does not work on Android 11.

I always see a msg as:

```
I/cmd: oneway function results will be dropped but finished with status OK and parcel size 4
```

The exitvalue returned is 255.

If I execute this command via "adb shell svc wifi disable", it works well on Android 9 and Android 11.

Any one tried this? Is there any other alternative to "svc wifi disable" for Android 11?

Comment: NOTE: I have tried with DO, PO mode

Answer (score 0):

Well this is probably as the WIFI enable/disable API's are disabled, it is also restricted from the shell to execute it.
This is probably no more feasible to achieve this using svc shell command programmatically.